# Sharepoint : application page could not find SPList

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, url, application-pages, getlist

I have an application page: ApprovedReassessments with this url :

```
http://.../Sites/spain/_layouts/pw/ApprovedReassessments.aspx
```

and I have a library : DropDownLibrary with this url:

```
  http://.../sites/Spain/DropDownLibrary/Forms/AllItems.aspx
```

when I try to call this library in the application page :

```
     string DROPDOWNLIBRARY_FIELDS = "<FieldRef Name='{0}' /><FieldRef Name='{1}' /><FieldRef Name='{2}' /><FieldRef Name='{3}' /><FieldRef Name='{4}' /><FieldRef Name='{5}' /><FieldRef Name='{6}' /><FieldRef Name='{7}' /><FieldRef Name='{8}' /><FieldRef Name='{9}' /><FieldRef Name='{10}' />";
    SPQuery objQuery = new SPQuery();
    objQuery.ViewFields = string.Format(DROPDOWNLIBRARY_FIELDS, SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.AGENTID_FIELD, SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.ID_FIELD,
                         SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.CREATED_FIELD, SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.SALESFORCECASENUMBER_FIELD, SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.COUNTRY_CODE_FIELD,
                         SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.FILELEAFREF_FIELD, SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.FILEREF_FIELD, SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.ASSESST_STATUS_FIELD,
                         SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.REVIEWTYPE_FIELD, SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.PAXORCARGO_FIELD, SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.SUBMITTEDDATE_FIELD
                         );
  objQuery.Query = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ID\"/><Value Type=\"Integer\">" + salesforceCaseNumber + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ID\"/><Value Type=\"Integer\">" + agentId + "</Value></Eq></And></Where>";                   
 SPList dropDownList = this.currentWeb.GetList(SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(this.currentWeb.ServerRelativeUrl, DocumentLibrary.DROPDOWN)); ...
```

the last line return this error :

```
 cannot complete this action please try again
```

PS : I have a webpart who call the same library, and it works but not in application page any idea please ?

Answer (score 1):

```
currentWeb.Lists["DropDownList"]
```

Lists takes the title or the list id.  What you're passing in looks like the partial URL.

Comment: I m trying the second code  SPList dropDownList = this.currentWeb.GetList(SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(this.currentWeb.ServerRelativeUrl, DocumentLibrary.DROPDOWN));  because it works in webpart and not in application page error :  cannot complete this action please try again

Answer (score 0):

Check `http://<url>/FormServerTemplates`

> Go to the above URL > Settings > Library Settings > Permission to this Library and provide permission to your user.

Also, check if it's just for one library or its happening for all the library. looks a permission issue.

Comment: I will check it but I m not sure because in a webpart (in home page) I can access to library, with same code

Comment: Webpart must be using elevated priviliges thats why

Comment: no elevated priviliges on the webpart, and I have full control on the doc library, but still not working

Comment: In Form Server Templates also you have permission too?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution and it works :

```
using (SPSite curSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
            {
                curSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                using (SPWeb curWeb = curSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    curWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    SPList list2 = curWeb.GetList(SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(curWeb .ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/'), "/Lists/ListName"));
                    curWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                }
                curSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            }
```